# How to add polyfills for external libraries in babel with rollup

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs

I'm using rollup to build my (AMD/UMD) project. There's an external dependency to a library that uses ES features such as: Map, Symbol,  Array.from, etc. which aren't supported in Internet Explorer. Since the library is external, babel doesn't seem to transpile the library, meaning those features are never polyfilled.

Is there a way to tell babel to include this library for polyfilling via @babel/preset-env?

The rollup config I have looks something like this:

```
{
  // omitted ...
  external: [
    'vue',
    /^@pnp.*/, // uses Map, Symbol, Array.from, ...
  ],
  plugins: [
    babel ({
      configFile: false,
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      exclude: /node_modules\/(?!vue-runtime-helpers)/,
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.es6', '.es', '.mjs', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
      presets: [
        ['@babel/preset-env', {
          corejs: 3,
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          ignoreBrowserslistConfig: false,
          targets: {
            browsers: browserslist, // includes IE11
          },
        }],
      ],
    }),
  ]
}
```

`vue` seems to work as an external dependency OOTB, because they provide a build that's IE-compatible, while pnpjs does not.

Answer (score 0):

Babel won't be able to detect needed polyfills for external modules but you can include [`@pnp/polyfill-ie11`](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/polyfill/) in your app. Make sure to not mark it as external.